# Iterating through LinkedHashSet with switch case cause a matching parameter to get skipped in Java 8

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am iterating through a LinkedHashSet() and I am using switch to capture some of the values.

```
iterating through 
-i 5 -r 3 -t 3 -d 55.55.555.55

case "-i":
 int interval = Integer.parseInt(iterator.next().toString().trim());
 switch (interval) {
     case 5:
         goodConfigCollector.add("\t\t* Interval: " + interval);
         break;
      }
 break;
 case "-r":
 int retries = Integer.parseInt(iterator.next().toString().trim());
 switch (retries) {
     case 3:
         goodConfigCollector.add("\t\t* Retries: " + retries);
         break;
          }
 break;
 case "-t":
 int timeout = Integer.parseInt(iterator.next().toString().trim());
 switch (timeout) {
     case 3:
         goodConfigCollector.add("\t\t* Timeout: " + timeout);
         break;
      }
 break;
 case "-d":
 String dip = iterator.next().toString().trim();
 switch (dip) {
     case “55.55.555.55”:
         goodConfigCollector.add("\t\t* D-IP: " + dip);
         break;
     }
 break;

to troubleshoot, I printed out each case 
case "-i":
System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
case "-r":
System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
case "-t":
System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
case "-d":
System.out.println(iterator.next().toString());
```

Output

```
-i -> 5  -r -> 3 -t ->  -d -> 55.55.555.55
```

Note that I didn't get a value for -t which explains why I am receiving the error in the first place.

```
error when -r and -t value are the same:
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-d"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
```

Note my string has the value of r = 3 and the value of t = 3. So if I changed the value of -t to a different value like 7 or anything else, then re-print. I get a value for t.

Changed my string to
    -i 5 -r 3 -t 7 -d 55.55.555.55

```
Output now is equal to 
-i --> 5 -r --> 3 -t --> 7 -d --> 55.55.555.55
```

Comment: Have you tried printing "[" + timeout + "]" just to verify its value?

Comment: you'll need to tell what errors you get

Comment: which java version you are using? it will work  in java 7 and above.

Comment: @Rustam: he's talking about runtime behaviour, he wouldn't get this far if it wasn't a String he 's switching on

Comment: @Rustam: Switch can accept Strings since Java 7. This is true. But Moe says he gets errors on "run time" not on "compile time"! So it is sth else.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: So far, I understand he doesn't get errors, but his case doesn't match.

Comment: I updated the question with the error message and more detail. Thanks for looking.

Comment: what is your line 120 in MainController.java?

Comment: I am printing the file I am parsing  List<String> aryLines = file.OpenFile();
        aryLines.forEach(n -> {
           System.out.println(n);
       });

Comment: Just show us an MCVE.

Comment: I changed the question with more detail, please take a look now.

Comment: regarding the MCVE, i am new to the Java world how can I obtain that?

Answer (score 1):

the error message is pretty clear:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-d"
```

It seems somewhere in you code you try to convert the string `-d` to a number

Comment: Not even "somewhere", but at `ciacv.ReadFile.testScan(ReadFile.java:2437)`. OP, take a look at line 2437 in your class, that's where your problem is. Not the switch case.

Comment: gefei, you are correct, there is something wrong with -d... I updated my question to reflect the current issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue: My String has duplicate values

```
String
 -r 3 -t 3 -d 55.555.555
```

So when I stored them into a LinkedHashSet, they were stored as -r 3 -t -d 55.555.555 dropping the duplicate 3 after the -t.

When my case "-t"; got matched, I attempted to convert .next() to integer. In this case .next() is equal to -d. Hence the error I recived.

```
So the solution is:
instead of using LinkedHashSet I should be using a list instead 
List<String> set1 = new ArrayList<>();
as it allows duplicates.  Thanks all for your help. 

Side Note: I am not sure why I got -4 for this question. 
But anyways whoever gave me the -4 points, thanks for looking.
```